# How to get Android Volley to parse my Json response to a POJO in the worker thread

Tags: java, android, json, gson, android-volley

I currently have the following code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, Network.getFullUrl("/Account/Login"),
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        showProgress(false);
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        LoginResponseViewModel model = gson.fromJson(
                                response, LoginResponseViewModel.class);

                        if (model.Status) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                    MainMenuActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            mPasswordView
                                    .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                            
                        showProgress(false);
                        //TODO: show error
                    }
                });
        Network.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

How can I get Volley to do the gson.fromJson in the worker thread and then just pass me the correct object I want?

This was it will help reduce load on the UI / Main thread and then simplify code as well.

Can I use the default `JsonObjectRequest` or am I going to have to create a custom request type?

Comment: You should use a custom request type and override the parseNetworkResponse method, more here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

You should manipulate your `gson.fromJson()` as

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 LoginResponseViewModel model = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), LoginResponseViewModel.class);
```

It is because `gson.fromJson()` takes `JsonObject` parameter that is in Gson library within `com.google.gson.JsonObject` and you are sending `JSONObject` that is  in `org.json.JSONObject`